# Combining brace expansion and output redirection

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, io-redirection

Often, I use parameter expansion on the command-line, such as

```
cp a.{ext1,ext2}
```

which is expands to

```
cp a.ext1 a.ext2
```

However, in many cases I do not use `cp`, but another tool, let's call it `cat`, and I would do some output redirection, like

```
cat a.ext1 > a.ext2
```

In my case `a` can vary, or be quite long, so I would like to be able to use some sort of brace expansion, that at least needs only one occurrence of `a` in the one-liner. How can I obtain that?

I am specifically using

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)
```

but answers using other shells are also appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can type:

`$ cat very-long-filename.ext1Ctrl+WCtrl+Y>Ctrl+YBackspace2`

Or:

`$ cat very-long-filename.Ctrl+WCtrl+Yext1>Ctrl+Yext2`

To really use brace expansion, note that:

```
cat a.ext1 > a.ext2
```

Can also be written:

```
cat > a.ext2 a.ext1
```

However you cannot do:

`cat > a.ext{2,1}`

However, you could do:

```
eval cat \> a.ext{2,1}
```

In `zsh`, you could also use an anonymous function:

```
(){cat $1 > $2} a.ext{1,2}
```

Or:

```
(){cat ${1}1 > ${1}2} a.ext
```

Comment: Interesting edit! With the `cat > a.ext{2,1}` I get an ambiguous redirect. Any idea why this is? Does `{` do anything special?

Comment: @Bernhard You get that _ambiguous redirect_ in `bash` any time you pass something that expands to more than one argument to a redirection operator. Same in `a='a b'; echo > $a`. With `zsh`, that would do some _mult_ios_ (tee the output to both files)

Comment: Does that imply that bash executes the redirect before the expansion? I would think that it expands first, an then operatres (basically like an alias would), but apparently my view is a bit naive.

Comment: Funny detail: in zsh, `cat > a.ext{2,1} other_file` does function. But it outputs the content of `other_file` to _both_ `a.ext1` and `a.ext2`. I don't know how it manages to duplicate the redirection.

Comment: @lgeorget, as I said, that's the [multios feature](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) whereby `zsh` implements a `tee` internally.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, yes, sorry. I somehow skipped that part of your comment on first reading. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

What about:-

```
f=really-long-filename; cat "$f.ext1" > "$f.ext2"
```

Comment: That works, but is not really what I am looking for, as I would still have to retype the `${PR}`

Answer (score 2):

Use a shell function

```
 xyx () { cat "$1".$2 > "$1".$3; }
```

then

```
xyz fie foo fum
```

expands to

```
cat fee.foo > fee.fum
```

Comment: Extensions `.1` and `.2` are typically not universal for me.

Comment: Modified answer to take parameters.