# Can I reference a command before '&&' after '&&'

Tags: bash, zsh

Not sure how else to phrase the question, but basically, I often find myself running a command like `vagrant` to bring up the VM, and then ssh into it like below:

```
vagrant up && vagrant ssh
```

Short of writing my own function or script, is there a way to "reuse" the `vagrant` portion in the second part of the command?

Comment: You might find this answer on a related question helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140513/14084

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With `(t)csh`, `bash` or `zsh` history expansion you *could* write:

```
vagrant up && !#:0 ssh
```

But, seriously, you wouldn't

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but yeah. Probably just easier to do an alias or function. Thanks!

Comment: @glenn could you please explain what `!#:0` stands for. If we replace 0 with 1, 2 or any number, then what would it imply?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction -- `!#` refers to the line you're currently typing, and `:0` is the first word in the line ("vagrant"). So `!#:1` would be "up", etc

Comment: Holy cow people. Stop upvoting my answer. Consider the mental effort required to a) retype "vagrant", or b) first remember "!#:0" and then type it.

Answer (score 13):

You could do:

```
eval vagrant\ {'up &&',ssh}
```

but that would not make it easier.

You could always make a function

```
doall() {
  cmd=$1; shift
  for arg do
    "$cmd" "$arg" || return
  done
}
```

And then:

```
doall vagrant up ssh
```

Comment: Nice approach! I like the idea of being able to use it for more than one application. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Not directly an answer but, two alternatives maybe worth looking at (too much for a comment):

1. Alias

   If you repeatedly use a command, you can put an alias into your `~/.bashrc`

   ```
   alias vassh="vagrant up && vagrant ssh"
   ```
2. Command line history

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> let's you search your previous commands. This will be much faster than using variables...

Answer (score 4):

```
 v=vagrant; $v up && $v ssh
```

That might be close to what you're looking for.

Here's a function that - in `bash` - will print the first word in command position for the current compound command:

```
rc() { $(set -f; unset IFS
        set -- $(history 1)
        IFS="(){};|'\\\"&#"
        set \ $2;IFS=\ ;set -- $*
        printf %s "$1") "$@"; }
```

With that you could do:

```
vagrant up && rc ssh
```

An example:

```
echo up && rc ssh
```

#### OUTPUT

```
up
ssh
```

or...

```
set -x
(echo);rc 'times two'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
+ echo

+ rc 'times two'
++ set -f
++ unset IFS
+++ history 1
++ set -- 549 '(echo);rc' ''\''times' 'two'\'''
++ IFS='(){};|'\''\"&#'
++ set ' ' echo '' rc
++ IFS=' '
++ set -- echo rc
++ printf %s echo
+ echo 'times two'
times two
```